# Prove: $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = f(a) \int_a^c g(x) dx + f(b) \int_c^b g(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f$ and $g$ be real-valued continuous functions on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$. Given that $f$ is
>   increasing and $g$ is positive on $[a,b]$. Prove the following:  $$
>  \int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = f(a) \int_a^c g(x) dx + f(b) \int_c^b g(x) dx
>  $$ where $c$ $ϵ$ $[a,b]$.

I would have attempted this by working from the RHS, which gives the following: 
$$f(a) \int_a^c g(x) dx + f(b) \int_c^b g(x) dx = f(a) [g(c)-g(a)] + f(b) [g(b)-g(c)]$$
by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Part II).

Subsequently, i would expand it as: 
$$ f(a)g(c)- f(a)g(a) + f(b)g(b) - f(b)g(c) $$

Working from LHS, 
$$ \int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) $$

As such, 
$ f(a)g(c) - f(b)g(c) \implies g(c) [f(a) - f(b)] $ must be $0$.

How do i derive the above to complete this proof?

Comment: $$f(a) \int_a^c g(x) dx + f(b) \int_c^b g(x) dx = f(a) [g(c)-g(a)] + f(b) [g(b)-g(c)]$$ Wrong !!

Comment: Presumably you're trying to show that there is some $c$ for which the identity holds.

Comment: @carmichael561 i'm trying to show the LHS from the RHS, how do i approach it?

Comment: That approach is unlikely to succeed, as the identity is certainly not true for all $c$. Instead, try using the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Write $H(x)=f(a)\int_a^xg(x)dx+f(b)\int_x^bg(x)dx-\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx$. $H(a)\geq 0$ and $H(b)\leq 0$.

$H(a)=\int_a^b(f(b)-f(x))g(x)\geq 0$ since $f(b)\geq f(x)$ and $g(x)\geq 0$ $H(b)=\int_a^b(f(a)-f(x))g(x)\leq 0$, so there exists $c$ such that  $H(c)=0$ i.e
$f(a)\int_a^cg(x)d(x)+f(b)\int_c^bg(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on how you derive the following: "$H(b)=\int_a^b(f(a)-f(x))g(x)\leq 0$, so there exists $c$ such that  $H(c)=0$"?

Comment: $H(a)\geq 0, H(b)\leq 0$ and apply IVT.